# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm trying to get my on_message event to work without the commands being blocked. I added a `await client.process_commands(message)` line, but now its telling me that 'str' object has no attribute 'send' which I have no idea what it means. Here is the code I'm working on.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower().startswith("hi"):
        await message.content.send('hello brotha')
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Any solutions??

Comment: Well, have you checked the documentation? It's sensible that the contents of a message is a string which obviously doesn't have `send()` method. Are you sure you're using it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`message.content` is type `str`. You're calling `.send('hello brotha')` on it, thus causing that error message. If you're trying to reply to the initial message, you should be doing this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower().startswith("hi"):
        await message.reply('hello brotha')
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

You should refer to the discord.py documentation.